# javascript remoting - receive wrapper class list in javascript thru remoting and then send to visualforce page component

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

I am working on javascript remoting, thru my remote action method I am returning  wrapper class list. how can I pass that received wrapper list in javascript to visualforce page component

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not an SObject, you're going to need to parse that wrapper class list in the Visualforce page component's controller. Making sure that the wrapper class list is a string in JSON format should allow you to use Apex's JSON parser and grab the values you need to use it in the Visualforce page component.

Edit with coding example:
Lets say you want to use a javascript list of People in Salesforce, so starting off with the javascript function.

`function createContactsFromPeople(listOfPeople) {
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.ContactLogic.createContactsFromPeople}',
        listOfPeople, 
        function(result, event){
           if (event.status) {
               // confirm on your page it's all good
           } else {
               // display error message
           }
    );
}`

You can handle it in Apex with a method like this with the listOfPeople string looking like this:
`[{"person":{ 
        "name":"Johnson"
   }
 },
  {"person":{
      "name": "Smith"
   }
 }]`

`@RemoteAction
 global static void createContactsFromPeople(String listOfPeople) {
     JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(listOfPeople);
     while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
         if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
            Contact c = new Contact();
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
            (parser.getCurrentName() == 'name')) {
                // Get the value.
                parser.nextToken();
                // Compute the grand total price for all invoices.
                c.LastName = parser.getText();
            }
            insert c;
         }
     }
}`

Sorry for the weird formatting, I'm not very good at formatting code in this rich text editor.

Comment: That is a great answer, do you think you can enhance it with some sample code for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an formal type declared you should try to use it in the deserialization.  See these examples:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008r36IAA

```
(List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize(json_string, List<String>.class)
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm

```
public class Car {
    public String make;
    public String year;
}
public void parse() {        
    Car c = (Car)JSON.deserializeStrict(
        '{"make":"SFDC","year":"2020"}',
        Car.class);
    System.assertEquals(c.make, 'SFDC');
    System.assertEquals(c.year, '2020');
}
```